# Assign group id to sequence of concecutive unique values in timeseries

Tags: r, datetime

I am dealing with a big timeseries with one column containing four different sensors and one column containing the mesured values. I need to assign an id to measurements that belong to the same time. The problem is, that the timing of measurements differs slightly for each device, thus i cannot simply group them by timestamp. In a data frame ordered by time, measurements that should be grouped can be identified by sequences of unique device Ids. The problem here is, that at one time 4 devices record a value and another time 3 devices record a value. My data looks like this.

```
       timestamp                  device   measurement
    1  2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313 sdr_03   49.868820
    2  2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043 sdr_02   54.160831
    3  2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312 sdr_03   48.974476
    4  2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454 sdr_02   50.808674
    5  2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833 sdr_03   50.533058
    6  2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798 sdr_04   51.143322
    7  2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308 sdr_02   57.447151
    8  2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433 sdr_04   50.012745
    9  2019-08-27 09:16:56.761776 sdr_01   71.500305
    10 2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510 sdr_02   56.851177
    11 2019-08-27 09:16:57.333628 sdr_04   60.390141
    12 2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972 sdr_01   73.470345
```

which you can reproduce with this:

```
my_data<-data.frame(timestamp = c("2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313","2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043","2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312",
                                       "2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454", "2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833","2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798",
                                       "2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308", "2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433", "2019-08-27 09:16:56.761776",
                                       "2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510" ,"2019-08-27 09:16:57.333628", "2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972"),
               device=c("sdr_03", "sdr_02", "sdr_03", "sdr_02", "sdr_03" ,"sdr_04", "sdr_02", "sdr_04" ,"sdr_01", "sdr_02" ,"sdr_04",
                        "sdr_01"),
               measurement=c(49.868820, 54.160831, 48.974476, 50.808674, 50.533058, 51.143322,57.447151,50.012745, 71.500305,56.851177,
                             60.390141, 73.470345)
               )
```

I need to assign the same value to consecutive rows as long as none of the elements in the previous rows of column device appears again

```
             timestamp        device   measurement match_id
1  2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313 sdr_03   49.868820        1
2  2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043 sdr_02   54.160831        1
3  2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312 sdr_03   48.974476        2
4  2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454 sdr_02   50.808674        2
5  2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833 sdr_03   50.533058        3
6  2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798 sdr_04   51.143322        3
7  2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308 sdr_02   57.447151        3
8  2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433 sdr_04   50.012745        4
9  2019-08-27 09:16:56.761776 sdr_01   71.500305        4
10 2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510 sdr_02   56.851177        4
11 2019-08-27 09:16:57.333628 sdr_04   60.390141        5
12 2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972 sdr_01   73.470345        5
```

which you can get from:

```
my_data<-data.frame(timestamp = c("2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313","2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043","2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312",
                                   "2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454", "2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833","2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798",
                                   "2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308", "2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433", "2019-08-27 09:16:56.761776",
                                   "2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510" ,"2019-08-27 09:16:57.333628", "2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972"),
           device=c("sdr_03", "sdr_02", "sdr_03", "sdr_02", "sdr_03" ,"sdr_04", "sdr_02", "sdr_04" ,"sdr_01", "sdr_02" ,"sdr_04",
                    "sdr_01"),
           measurement=c(49.868820, 54.160831, 48.974476, 50.808674, 50.533058, 51.143322,57.447151,50.012745, 71.500305,56.851177,
                         60.390141, 73.470345),match_id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5) )
```

I have been searching for answers for three days now. Any help is very much appreciated.

Allan Camerons dplyr solution results in match ids that reappear later in the data frame- see lines 1,2,6,9. There may be less than 4 devices recording at one time, thus solutions that always expect the same number of recording devices for each measurement won't work.

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   device [4]
   timestamp                  device measurement new_id
   <dttm>                     <fct>        <dbl>  <int>
 1 2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313 sdr_03        49.9      1
 2 2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043 sdr_02        54.2      1
 3 2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312 sdr_03        49.0      2
 4 2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454 sdr_02        50.8      2
 5 2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833 sdr_03        50.5      3
 6 2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798 sdr_04        51.1      1
 7 2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308 sdr_02        57.4      3
 8 2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433 sdr_04        50.0      2
 9 2019-08-27 09:16:56.761775 sdr_01        71.5      1
10 2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510 sdr_02        56.9      4
11 2019-08-27 09:16:57.333627 sdr_04        60.4      3
12 2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972 sdr_01        73.5      2
```

While Sotos solution results in more consecutive match ids than unique devices exist. E.g. lines 5-9

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   timestamp           device measurement new_id
   <chr>               <fct>        <dbl>  <int>
 1 2019-08-27 07:29:20 sdr_03        49.9      1
 2 2019-08-27 07:29:20 sdr_02        54.2      1
 3 2019-08-27 07:29:21 sdr_03        49.0      2
 4 2019-08-27 07:29:21 sdr_02        50.8      2
 5 2019-08-27 08:57:01 sdr_03        50.5      3
 6 2019-08-27 08:57:02 sdr_04        51.1      3
 7 2019-08-27 09:16:56 sdr_02        57.4      3
 8 2019-08-27 09:16:56 sdr_04        50.0      3
 9 2019-08-27 09:16:56 sdr_01        71.5      3
10 2019-08-27 09:16:57 sdr_02        56.9      4
11 2019-08-27 09:16:57 sdr_04        60.4      4
12 2019-08-27 09:16:57 sdr_01        73.5      4
```

Both solutions work great (thanks!) if timediffs between measurements are >0.7 sec or 4 devices recorded at the same time. Sadly, most of the time this is not the case. I think, a solution that ignores timestamps and rather checks for duplicates in consecutive rows might be better. I found many solutions for repeated values using rle() or data.table, but no solution to identify sequences of unique values. Please help me out here!

Comment: Maybe `data$match_id <- as.numeric(as.factor(data$timestamp))` ?

Comment: Thanks for editing, Allan. My first question on stack overflow!

Comment: I#am sorry, for readability i did not take the real timestamps, they look more like this: 2019-08-27 09:29:03.09279.

Comment: Then you need to reformat the date, keep only "yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss", then try my suggestion. Please edit your example, and provide realistic data.

Comment: Thanks zx8754. To clarify my problem, i am recording vhf-signals from tags, that are glued to the fur of bats with rtl-sdrs. The timing between consecutive signals varies with the bodytemperature. I gets faster with high bodytemperature (<0.5 sec). The time difference between measurements of the same signal recorded by the different devices may be close or the same as the timedifference to the next signal. Working with timestamps is not an option here.

Comment: @zx8754 There are sometimes multiple measurements in the same second by the same device, but we want the ID to increment when that happens, so rounding and factoring the time stamp won't work here.

Comment: Hey everybody! First of all, iam amazed by the speed and quality of all your answers. Second I am sorry for not providing real data in the beginnign. I have edited the uper section. @AllanCameron, very nice and elegant solution but same match ids appear later in the rows, eventhough timestamp is at least more than 1 second later.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure I really overthought it, but it's a working solution,

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
 mutate(timestamp = format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) %>%
 group_by(timestamp) %>% 
 mutate(new = data.table::rleid(duplicated(device))) %>% 
 group_by(timestamp, new) %>% 
 mutate(new1 = row_number() + new) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(new_id = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(new1) < 0))) %>% 
 select(-c(new, new1))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 4
>    timestamp           device measurement new_id
>    <fct>               <fct>        <dbl>  <int>
>  1 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_02        80.2      1
>  2 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_01        71.7      1
>  3 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_04        74.2      1
>  4 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_03        62.6      1
>  5 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_02        77.1      2
>  6 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_01        69.2      2
>  7 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_03        62.1      2
>  8 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_02        77.1      3
>  9 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_01        54.6      3
> 10 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_03        64.3      3
> 11 2019-08-27 09:48:56 sdr_02        66.5      4
> 12 2019-08-27 09:48:56 sdr_01        71.7      4
> ```

Comment: great solution but more than four consecutive match ids appear if you use the data i just provided in the upper section. I realy think there must be an solution that ignores timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't this be done more simply?

```r
library(dplyr)

df               %>% 
group_by(device) %>% 
mutate(new_id = seq_len(length(device)), timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   device [4]
#>    timestamp           device measurement new_id
#>    <dttm>              <fct>        <dbl>  <int>
#>  1 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_02        80.2      1
#>  2 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_01        71.7      1
#>  3 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_04        74.2      1
#>  4 2019-08-27 09:48:54 sdr_03        62.6      1
#>  5 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_02        77.1      2
#>  6 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_01        69.2      2
#>  7 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_03        62.1      2
#>  8 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_02        77.1      3
#>  9 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_01        54.6      3
#> 10 2019-08-27 09:48:55 sdr_03        64.3      3
#> 11 2019-08-27 09:48:56 sdr_02        66.5      4
#> 12 2019-08-27 09:48:56 sdr_01        71.7      4
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the OP's comments, it seems the best way to do this is to just define a function that keeps a running tally of devices it has encountered and increments whenever it reaches a duplicate.

```r
# Code                                     # Pseudocode
# =======================================  # ===================================
group_instances <- function(my_labels)     #
{                                          #
  my_labels <- as.character(my_labels)     # (Ensure we use a character vector)
                                           #
  result    <- numeric(length(my_labels))  # Create a numeric result vector
  matches   <- as.character(my_labels[1])  # Create tally of encountered devices
                                           #
  for(i in seq_along(my_labels)[-1])       # For each device record after the first
  {                                        #
    if(my_labels[i] %in% matches)          # If we have this device in our tally
    {                                      #
      matches   <- my_labels[i]            # Reset our tally of devices
      result[i] <- result[i - 1] + 1       # and increment our ID
    }                                      #
    else                                   # Otherwise
    {                                      #
      matches <- c(matches, my_labels[i])  # Add it to our tally of devices
      result[i] <- result[i - 1]           # and copy the ID from the row above
    }                                      #
  }                                        #
  return(result + 1)                       # Our IDs started at zero, so add one
}
```

Now we can do

```r
my_data %>% mutate(ID = as.factor(group_instances(device)))
#>                     timestamp device measurement ID
#> 1  2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313 sdr_03    49.86882  1
#> 2  2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043 sdr_02    54.16083  1
#> 3  2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312 sdr_03    48.97448  2
#> 4  2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454 sdr_02    50.80867  2
#> 5  2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833 sdr_03    50.53306  3
#> 6  2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798 sdr_04    51.14332  3
#> 7  2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308 sdr_02    57.44715  3
#> 8  2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433 sdr_04    50.01275  4
#> 9  2019-08-27 09:16:56.761776 sdr_01    71.50030  4
#> 10 2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510 sdr_02    56.85118  4
#> 11 2019-08-27 09:16:57.333628 sdr_04    60.39014  5
#> 12 2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972 sdr_01    73.47034  5
```

Comment: very nice and elegant solution but same match ids appear later in the rows, eventhough timestamp is at least more than 1 second later. There must be a solution without timestamps, just looking at consecutive and unique character strings.

Comment: @jgottwald thanks. Check my updated answer. Not as elegant, but does what you need and should be easy to follow

Answer (score 1):

I think a recursive function is required. Basically, you need to start a new group whenever the device is found in the previous group. Here is an implementation in `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
IntegerVector dev_not_in_prev_grp(IntegerVector device, int ndev) {
    int i, j, k, sz = device.size();
    std::vector<bool> exists(ndev);
    IntegerVector res(sz);

    for (k=0; k<ndev; k++) 
        exists[k] = false;

    for (i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        if (exists[device[i]-1]) {
            res[i] = 1;

            for (k=0; k<ndev; k++) 
                exists[k] = false;
        } 
        exists[device[i]-1] = true;
    }

    return(res);
}
")
```

usage:

```
ndev <- 4L
devmap <- setNames(1L:ndev, sprintf("sdr_%02d", 1L:ndev))    
cumsum(dev_not_in_prev_grp(devmap[my_data$device], ndev)) + 1L
```

output:

```
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that uses `Reduce()` and `%in%` to assign IDs by matching subsequent with earlier device values and resetting when there is a match.

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
    mutate(match_id = cumsum(lengths(
        Reduce(function(x, y)
            if (y %in% x)
                y
            else
                c(x, y), as.integer(as.factor(device)), accumulate = TRUE)
    ) == 1))

                    timestamp device measurement match_id
1  2019-08-27 07:29:20.671313 sdr_03    49.86882        1
2  2019-08-27 07:29:20.932043 sdr_02    54.16083        1
3  2019-08-27 07:29:21.839312 sdr_03    48.97448        2
4  2019-08-27 07:29:21.850454 sdr_02    50.80867        2
5  2019-08-27 08:57:01.990833 sdr_03    50.53306        3
6  2019-08-27 08:57:02.022798 sdr_04    51.14332        3
7  2019-08-27 09:16:56.454308 sdr_02    57.44715        3
8  2019-08-27 09:16:56.482433 sdr_04    50.01275        4
9  2019-08-27 09:16:56.761776 sdr_01    71.50030        4
10 2019-08-27 09:16:57.305510 sdr_02    56.85118        4
11 2019-08-27 09:16:57.333628 sdr_04    60.39014        5
12 2019-08-27 09:16:57.612972 sdr_01    73.47034        5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works. I have used a for loop to address the issue. You need to look at the "match_id" column. running_string is for reference.

```
my_data$match_id <- 1
my_data$running_string <- ''

test_str <- ''


for(i in (1:nrow(my_data))){
  if(grepl(my_data$device[i],test_str)){
    my_data$match_id[i] <- my_data$match_id[i-1] + 1
    test_str <- as.character(my_data$device[i])
  } else{
    test_str <- paste0(test_str,my_data$device[i])
    if(i > 1){
       my_data$match_id[i] <- my_data$match_id[i-1] 
    }

  }
  my_data$running_string[i] <- test_str
}
head(my_data,20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Seshadri! I Tested your approach but it did not work.

Comment: Could you let me know what error you got (if you have time) or if the result was incorrect ?